# Decoupling capacitors for ADC

Tags: decoupling-capacitor, texas-instruments

I have this ADS6125 adc. In the datasheet it is written that this ADC uses internal decoupling:

1. "capacitors on-chip eliminates the need for external decoupling" (p.45)
2. "As ADS612X already includes internal decoupling, minimal external decoupling can be used without loss in performance" (p.55)

It says minimal decoupling is enough. But what is minimal?

In my design I am using 3 decoupling caps for each supply pin. Could I get in trouble for using too many decoupling caps?

ADS6125 datasheet:
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads6125.pdf?ts=1603138441413&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FADS6125

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ADS6125 has an Evaluation Module (EVM), here: https://www.ti.com/tool/ADS6125EVM

This includes a schematic, including recommended bypassing. TI is good like that.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an evaluation board it's always helpful to check the schematics and layout of the eval board. If they don't use any external decoupling caps, you should also be fine with none, but you also could place one to be on the safe side.

To much decoupling caps could leed to the problem, that your current flow in the "power on"-moment is to high for your power supply or your pcb in generell. But you really need a lot of decoupling caps, so that this could be a problem.